# How to reference a cell's current value in calculation for its new value?

Tags: excel, circular-reference, inventory

I'm trying to create a stocklist that updates itself day by day using the TODAY() function.

Stock used is different each day of the week. Using

```
    IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),...)
```

where ... contains the value if true statement.

However, if it true needs to update the cell's value by subtracting the stock used on that day. I cannot find a way to do it without circular referencing errors. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You can allow circular references but, this is volatile as it will subtract each time that excel calculates not just once a day.  You will need vba, with a method to check if the value has already been subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

Circular reference errors happen when a cell references itself in some way - See this article for a very clear explanation: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/circular-reference.html

You should try using "trace dependents" and splitting your formulas into multiple "helper columns". 
Also, would be helpful to see exact examples of each of your formulas / values in a row.